# Javascript mathematical onkeyup issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I can't for the life of me figure out the following problem (I'm not so great with JavaScript).

This is the code I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){

<?php print("var base = " . $cash2points . " ;\n");?>
   document.getElementById('numberField').onkeyup = function() {
      if(this.value.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
         return;
      }
      var number = parseInt(this.value);
      if(isNaN(number)) return;
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = number * base;
   };
   document.getElementById('numberField').onkeyup();


<?php print("var base1 = " . $points2cash . " ;\n");?>
   document.getElementById('numberField1').onkeyup = function() {
      if(this.value.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = '';
         return;
      }
      var number = parseInt(this.value);
      if(isNaN(number)) return;
      document.getElementById('result1').innerHTML = number * base1;
   };
   document.getElementById('numberField1').onkeyup();
}//]]>  

</script>
```

`$cash2points = 100` and `$points2cash = 0.01` the second part of the code with `base1` works like a charm, it will give me decimals in the `<span>` but when I enter something like `0.01` in `numberfield` where `base = $cash2points` it just gives me a `0`, but it should display `1` is there something I am missing, or is it just something that can't be done. I tried making `$cash2points = 100.00` but that still produced the same results.

I am pretty sure decimals come back as false for `isNaN` so I don't think that is the problem either.

Any tips or pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: `parseInt(this.value);` maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have wrapped `number` in `parseInt`, you're only going to get integer values back - and floats (like `0.01`) will be truncated to an integer. Try using `parseFloat` instead.

Comment: Works like a charm thanks so much! I really need to read up on the different parse functions